# Where is IBM ClearCase client (not ClearCase Remote Client) evaluation software installation for Windows?

Tags: clearcase

Where would you find an IBM ClearCase client (not CCRC ClearCase Remote client) evaluation software installation for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there isn't an "evaluation version" of ClearCase.
If you are registered as an IBM client, you can download the full product and then ask for an evaluation key.

There was also a remote session for you to [evaluate ClearCase](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/cccq_evalguide/part3/) or [ClearCase with Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/dw-r-cccq-evalguide/index.html) (you connect to a remote IBM server where the product is already installed and where you have 3 hours to explore).
But I don't know if this program is still active.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a valid Passport Advantage account to download most IBM products.

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/passportadvantage/pacustomers.html